# DPM 2012 R2 Error 30231 - Exchange 2013 Protection Group

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, scdpm

Hi all I seem to have an issue with DPM since I have changed over to new local disk storage. I have looked on the TechNet wiki [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394981) and the error we are getting is not listed - 30231.

I have changed local storage before and used DPMSync to reallocate protection groups space and after a consistency check, backups resume. This time all backups are working as usual apart from the Exchange Backup. Agent on the DPM server and Exchange server are both version 4.2.1594.0.

I have tried stopping protection for the group, whilst retaining data to keep online data, and this has not helped. I have seen this as a solution elsewhere, but very little else on this error.

Here is some of the error log, its a large log so I've only taken a few snippets that have errors in.

```
0EB4    2494    08/23   15:47:34.481    27  FindPrincipalServerBlock.cs(249)        5FD400E4-F8D7-46C3-8506-346275EAE85C    NORMAL  Found Principal server for DatasourceId = 15ac89e2-c5fa-49a6-9469-3b5a8b163113 Server= <SERVERNAME>
0EB4    1818    08/23   15:47:34.675    18  fsutils.cpp(4046)           WARNING Failed: Hr: = [0x80070002] : Encountered Failure: : lVal : HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError)
0EB4    1C20    08/23   15:47:35.802    27  FsmBlock.cs(178)        5FD400E4-F8D7-46C3-8506-346275EAE85C    WARNING Backup.ReplicaPreBackupBlock : RAPreBackup, StatusReason = Error (StatusCode = -2137454109, ErrorCode = VSSDatasourceCaptionMismatch, workitem = 26865e42-efaa-4a43-8841-b44f2da04fd4)
0EB4    1C20    08/23   15:47:35.802    27  FsmBlock.cs(178)        5FD400E4-F8D7-46C3-8506-346275EAE85C    WARNING <Status xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/dls/StatusMessages.xsd" StatusCode="-2137454109" Reason="Error" CommandID="RAPreBackup" CommandInstanceID="b726ee56-e0ac-40a1-b23f-f134f6b747cc" GuidWorkItem="26865e42-efaa-4a43-8841-b44f2da04fd4" TETaskInstanceID="5fd400e4-f8d7-46c3-8506-346275eae85c"><ErrorInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/dls/GenericAgentStatus.xsd" ErrorCode="30231" DetailedCode="-2137454109" DetailedSource="2"><Parameter Name="AgentTargetServer" Value="<SERVERNAME>"/></ErrorInfo><RAStatus><RAPreBackup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/dls/ArchiveAgent/StatusMessages.xsd"><BackupTime>131479768557280000</BackupTime><RAPreBackupSubTaskStatus>Completed</RAPreBackupSubTaskStatus><DSStatus><ComponentName>29f315c6-0df0-4e08-ae1e-39b32614f3c5</ComponentName><LogicalPath>Microsoft Exchange Server\Microsoft Information Store\<SERVERNAME></LogicalPath><BackupStamp></BackupStamp><Metadata></Metadata></DSStatus></RAPreBackup></RAStatus></Status>
0EB4    1C20    08/23   15:47:35.819    27  FsmBlock.cs(130)        5FD400E4-F8D7-46C3-8506-346275EAE85C    WARNING Backup.ReplicaPreBackupBlock : <-- Exited FSM block with FAILURE (errorCode = VSSDatasourceCaptionMismatch) ErrorInfo = VSSDatasourceCaptionMismatch 
0EB4    16D8    08/23   15:47:38.990    27  BackupMachine.cs(2185)      5FD400E4-F8D7-46C3-8506-346275EAE85C    WARNING BackupMachine : FAILURE - BACKUP, errorCode=VSSDatasourceCaptionMismatch
0EB4    16D8    08/23   15:47:38.991    01  TaskInstance.cs(803)        5FD400E4-F8D7-46C3-8506-346275EAE85C    WARNING &lt;q1:ErrorInfo ErrorCode="30231" DetailedCode="-2137454109" DetailedSource="2" ExceptionDetails="" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/dls/GenericAgentStatus.xsd"&gt;
```

If anyone can help uncover this that would be great.

EDIT - Not sure what has changed but now its throwing 30127 errors, these too are not on any documentation I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bit of an ambiguous error code; however, in a certain section of the SCDPM interface it says the caption is incorrect. Someone our end has updated the Exchange database name so its easier to query - spaces removed and shortened - and DPM does not auto refresh server changes, even when recreating a protection group.

I stopped protection, created a new protection group and then refreshed the host details. This picked up the new name of the database and the backup consistency check is current still running whereas before it would fail after 5 seconds.

EDIT - I should have noticed this with the whole VSSDatasourceCaptionMismatch